# fiddler v4.5.1.0 - get http-error-code 407

Tags: fiddler, http-status-code-407

I get Fiddler HTTP code 407 back. I have tried to define the authentication by "X-Session AutoAuth flag" in a rule , unsuccessful. "Automatically Authenticate" doesn't work too.

Here is a saz-file with the problem:

[SAZ-Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/em4skrqpy01t1h6/request_407.saz?dl=0)

Comment: Can you edit this question to include details of the request in the body of the post? Thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you *expect* your upstream proxy to demand authentication credentials? If so, which credentials does it require, your Windows credentials, or some others?